# A friend of mine vs. My friend

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

What is a difference between a friend of mine and my friend? Both are equally fine at any settings? Can this lead to any confusion or misunderstanding?

This question is different from how to use apostrophe s or of. As these two are quite common expressions in spoken English, the difference is beyond the range of how to use possessive forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say "my friend" to describe a close friend, whereas "a friend of mine" would be one of my more general friends.

Why would I say it like that? Suppose I am introducing my very close friend to someone, and I refer to her as "one of my friends". She is going to feel very unflattered, possibly think she is not special after all. It could come across as a put-down.

On the other hand, if I introduce a friend from my golf club as "one of my friends" that is exactly what he is. If I were to describe him as "my friend" he might look at me sideways and wonder if I want to make him that *special* friend.

Comment: I disagree wholeheartedly. The two are stylistically different and can be used in different contexts but can mean the same exact thing.

Comment: @Lambie I suggest you post a better answer. Didn't I explain very well why they are different? OP asked "Can this lead to any confusion or misunderstanding?"